# Semi-infinite string with free end

Tags: partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

I want to understand, one dimensional semi infinite string with free end geometrically..

Consider the semi infinite string with free end

$u_{tt}=c^2u_{xx}$

$u(x,0)=f(x), 0\leq x<\infty$

$u_t(x,0)=g(x), 0\leq x<\infty$

$u_x(0,t)=0, t\geq 0$

My understanding

Suppose a rod is fixed at $x=0$. Assume that the knot of the string with rod is lose. If we pull the string from any point $x$, then, at $t=0$, we have an initial shape and initial stress in string, which implies,

$u(x,0)=f(x), 0\leq x<\infty$

$u_t(x,0)=g(x), 0\leq x<\infty.$

Now, if we leave the string, then a wave travels towards left hit the boundary. If knot is tight, then there is no displacement, and hence we have $u(0,t)=0$, which is fixed end condition.

If knot is lose, then we have displacement along the rod but this rod will not shift backward (that is, rod will not shift from x=0 to x=-0.001,say,) and hence we have

$u_x(0,t)=0, t\geq 0.$
that is no change with $x$ axis, which is free end condition.

Please tell whether I am correct or not?

Also, can anybody elaborate, what will happen if $u_x(0,t)\neq 0$?

Comment: That's correct. Now, what's your question? Just wanted to check your interpretation of the PDE equation and its conditions are right?

Comment: yes... I just want to confirm myself...

Comment: Can you elaborate if $u_x(0,t)=h(x)$? (In other words, what will happen if $u_x(0,t)\neq 0
$?)

Comment: When $x=0$ you cannot have a function like $h(x)$ simply because $x$ is determined. On the other hand, you may have $h(t)$ that is dependent on time and I explained it in the below answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your interpretation of the whole problem is correct.

About your question, if $u_x(0,t)\neq 0$, it means $u_x(0,t)= h(t)$.

$h(t)$ may vary by time. This means you have a source of energy which may vary by time.

> This source is responsible for **additional** waves on -Let's say like disturbances- starting from the fixed edge of the rod and spreading through the entire rod.

Another analogy is a rod which has heat transfer phenomena instead of displacement. When $u_x(0,t)\neq 0$ this means you have  a heat flux in $x=0$ that makes the rod warmer/cooler.

Comment: Thanks... may you give some references for more detail study?

Comment: You are welcome @Goldy. Please read the description of this link: http://hplgit.github.io/wavebc/doc/pub/._wavebc_cyborg002.html, section: "Feeding a wave from the boundary". What it also says is: "The movement of $u$ at the boundary will produce a wave that is by the PDE transported to the right into the domain."